# Using sqlsrv_query to get MS_DESCRIPTION fails

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to retrieve the MS_DESCRIPTION extended property from a SQL 2008 R2 database via the FN_ListExtendedProperty function, but the query returns no results. Executing the same query in the SMS works as expected. Is there another / better way to obtain this field?

-- Edit --

I am using sqlsrv_query to attempt the following query. I'd also like to avoid using sqlsrv_field_metadata as the sqlsrv_query function is handled by a class that doesn't provide direct access to the database, and returns record sets as 2-dimensional arrays.

Query:

```
SELECT
  CAST(Value AS VarChar(255)) AS [Label]

FROM
  FN_ListExtendedProperty('MS_DESCRIPTION', 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'TeamMemberPrivileges', 'column', NULL)
```

Comment: `SELECT CAST(Value AS VarChar(255)) AS [Label]
FROM sys.extended_properties
WHERE major_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TeamMemberPrivileges') and minor_id = 1 and name ='MS_DESCRIPTION' `

Comment: Had to remove minor_id and add the db name, but worked - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query [sys.extended_properites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/extended-properties-catalog-views-sys-extended-properties) directly:

```
SELECT CAST(Value AS VarChar(255)) AS [Label] 
FROM sys.extended_properties 
WHERE major_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TeamMemberPrivileges') AND name ='MS_DESCRIPTION'
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Under what circumstances would you use minor_id for?

Comment: @illmortem In orignal query you had `FN_ListExtendedProperty('MS_DESCRIPTION', 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'TeamMemberPrivileges', 'column', NULL)` with `level2_object_type` to to `COLUMN`. I translated it to `minor_id` `If class = 1, minor_id is the column_id if column, else 0 if object.` But you could skip it as you did.